# 3 Unicode Vulgar fractions - 1/7, 1/9 and 1/10 became box

Tags: character-encoding

Unicode provides us the code for printing few pre-defined vulgar fractions. When using the corresponding code for HTML, for 3 fractions they become box. They are 1/7, 1/9 and 1/10 [see attached screen shot]. This is seen on the sites also who are providing this code themselves. like: http://unicodefractions.com/

Can anyone help me out how to print them successfully on the web page?

[image: Vulgar Fraction Issue]

Comment: How is this related to salesforce.com? You might be better off asking this on [so] instead. If you're seeing boxes, it means your computer's system fonts do not support the characters, which means you may need to update your fonts or OS.

Comment: Ya, I had raised a flag immediately after posting. I had forgetfully posted on sf forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three characters:

- [VULGAR FRACTION ONE SEVENTH](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2150) (U+2150)
- [VULGAR FRACTION ONE NINTH](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2151) (U+2151)
- [VULGAR FRACTION ONE TENTH](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2152) (U+2152)

...have been introduced in [Unicode version 5.2](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/) (2009). This differentiates them from most other "vulgar fractions", which have been introduced in [Unicode version 1.1](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode1.1.0/) (1993).

In my browser, these characters in your [link](http://unicodefractions.com/) display correctly. So, I guess that your browser does not yet support Unicode version 5.2, and thus doesn't know the Unicode code points belonging to these characters.

I would suggest to update/reinstall your browser, or try with a different browser that supports Unicode version 5.2 and higher.